# Neo4j Spring Boot can only bind some entities to the database，not all

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j

I'm using neo4j-spring-boot in my project and I noticed that only some entities are bind to neo4j database.For example, I have line and site class:

```
@NodeEntity(label = "Line")
public class Line {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long lineid;
    private String lineserial;
    private float linelength;
    private String linename;

    public Line() {
    }

    public Line(String lineserial, String linename, float linelength) {
        this.lineserial = lineserial;
        this.linelength = linelength;
        this.linename = linename;
    }

    public Long getLineId() {
        return lineid;
    }

    public void setLineId(Long lineid) {
        this.lineid = lineid;
    }

    public String getLineSerial() {
        return lineserial;
    }

    public void setLineSerial(String lineserial) {
        this.lineserial = lineserial;
    }

    public float getLength() {
        return linelength;
    }

    public void setLineLength(int linelength) {
        this.linelength = linelength;
    }

    public String getLineName() {
        return linename;
    }

    public void setLineName(String linename) {
        this.linename = linename;
    }

    @Relationship(type = "Connect_To", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private List<Site> cSites;

    public List<Site> getSites() {
        return cSites;
    }

    public void addConnectSite(Site site) {
        if (this.cSites == null) {
            this.cSites = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.cSites.add(site);
    }

    @Relationship(type = "Cross_With", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)
    private List<Line> cLines;

    public List<Line> getLines() {
        return cLines;
    }

    public void addCrossLine(Line line) {
        if (this.cLines == null) {
            this.cLines = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.cLines.add(line);
    }
}

@NodeEntity(label = "Site")
public class Site {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long siteid;
    private String sitename;

    public Site() {
    }

    public Site(String sitename) {
        this.sitename = sitename;
    }

    public long getSiteId() {
        return siteid;
    }

    public void setSiteId(Long siteid) {
        this.siteid = siteid;
    }

    public String getSiteName() {
        return sitename;
    }

    public void setSiteName(String name) {
        this.sitename = name;
    }

}
```

and repositries

```
@Repository
public interface LineRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Line, Long> {

    Line findByLineserial(@Param("lineserial") String lineserial);

    Collection<Line> findByLinenameLike(@Param("linename") String linename);

    @Query("MATCH (l:Line)-[r:Connect_To]->(S:Site) RETURN l,r,s LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Line> graphConnectToSite(@Param("limit") int limit);

    @Query("MATCH (11:Site)-[r:Cross_With]-(lr:Line) RETURN ll,r,lr LIMIT {limit}")
    Collection<Line> graphCrossWithLine(@Param("limit") int limit);
}


@Repository
public interface SiteRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Site, Long> {
    Site findBySitename(@Param("sitename") String sitename);
}
```

and services

```
@Service
public class LineService {

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LineService.class);

    @Autowired
    private LineRepository lineRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Line findByTitle(String serial_number) {
        Line result = lineRepository.findByLineserial(serial_number);
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Collection<Line> findByLineNameLike(String name) {
        Collection<Line> result = lineRepository.findByLinenameLike(name);
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Line SaveLine(String serial_number, String line_name, float length) {
        if (lineRepository.findByLineserial(serial_number) != null) {
            return null;
        }
        Line line = new Line(serial_number, line_name, length);
        return lineRepository.save(line);
    }
}

@Service
public class SiteService {
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiteService.class);

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Site findBySiteName(String site_name) {
        Site result = siteRepository.findBySitename(site_name);
        return result;
    }

    @Transactional
    public Site SaveSite(String site_name) {
        if (siteRepository.findBySitename(site_name) != null) {
            System.out.print(site_name + "is already exist");
            return null;
        }
        Site site = new Site(site_name);
        //System.out.print(site_name+ siteRepository.save(site).getSiteId() + "is added successfully");
        Site result =  siteRepository.save(site);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I used RESTful to add nodes, than I found that only lines are added into the database while sites are not.And if I create a site node in neo4j database, I cannot find it by Site-Find Function.
Here is the log.

```
2019-11-06 17:19:33.147  INFO 2848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: MATCH (n:`Site`) WHERE n.`sitename` = { `sitename_0` } WITH n RETURN n, ID(n) with params {sitename_0=site1}
2019-11-06 17:19:33.159  INFO 2848 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: UNWIND {rows} as row MATCH (n) WHERE ID(n)=row.nodeId SET n:`Site` SET n += row.props RETURN row.nodeId as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeId=0, props={sitename=site1}}]}
2019-11-06 17:24:10.949  INFO 2848 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: MATCH (n:`Line`) WHERE n.`lineserial` = { `lineserial_0` } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)-[r_c1:`Connect_To`]->(s1:`Site`) | [ r_c1, s1 ] ], [ (n)-[r_c1:`Cross_With`]-(l1:`Line`) | [ r_c1, l1 ] ] ], ID(n) with params {lineserial_0=1254}
2019-11-06 17:24:10.954  INFO 2848 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: UNWIND {rows} as row CREATE (n:`Line`) SET n=row.props RETURN row.nodeRef as ref, ID(n) as id, {type} as type with params {type=node, rows=[{nodeRef=-11, props={linelength=11.2, linename=ABAB, lineserial=1254}}]}
```

I noticed that for lines the spring used a CREATE while for sites used a MATCH.However, they both used the **save** function from Neo4jRepository.

It will be of great help if someone can tell me why.

Comment: The are using neo4j for inserting is the reason `    @Relationship(type = "Cross_With", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)`. As neo4j supports only Unidirectional graph while creating nodes and relationships but they allow undirected lookup - please refer, https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html

Comment: @Jatish Thank you for your comment. I changed direction to Outgoing and try again. Unfortunately, the Sites still could not insert into the database, it seems to be some other problems in my project.

Comment: Did you try with `private Long siteid;` instead of  `private long siteid;`?

Comment: Do change accessor and mutator with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code changes required that resolved the issue-

> 1) Relationship direction   Neo4j support Unidirectional
>   relationship when persisting a node to node relation at this moment.
>   In addition to that, it allows an undirected relationship at the time of
>   lookup.

Update required:
  `@Relationship(type = "Cross_With", direction = Relationship.UNDIRECTED)` to either `Relationship.OUTGOING` or `Relationship.INCOMING`

reference: https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2013/10/11/neo4j-bidirectional-relationships.html

> 2) Neo4j spring-data supports auto-generated Id of wrapper type

- Long
- String

  update required:
  `private Long siteid;` instead of `private long siteid;`